# On GroupBy's *red* argument in nested groupings

Tags: gathering

The documentation for `GroupBy` includes the following cases, among others:

> `GroupBy[{elem1, elem2, … }, {fs1, fs2, … }]`
>   groups into nested associations using *fs*<sub>*i*</sub> at level *i*.
>
> `GroupBy[{elem1, elem2, … }, spec, red]`
>   applies the function red to reduce lists of values that are generated.

---

Now, when the *spec* argument in the second form is a list of functions {*f*<sub>1</sub>, …, *f*<sub>*n*</sub>}, IOW, in the case of a *n*-level grouping, it only makes sense that the *red* argument be applied at the *n*-th level of the resulting association, since this is the level where the "lists of values that are generated" end up.

Contrary to this expectation, the *red* argument *always* gets applied at the first level, even in the case of multi-level groupings.

---

For example, the 2-level `GroupBy` below fails with `Lists of unequal length` errors.

```
data = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 50]];
GroupBy[data, {Mod[#, 5] == 0 &, Mod[#, 6] == 0 &}, Total]
```

---

Is there some *general* way to specify the *red* argument so that it behaves properly in all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
GroupBy[data, {Mod[#, 5] == 0 &, Mod[#, 6] == 0 &}, Map[Total, #, {-2}]&]
```

> <|True -> <|False -> 4605, True -> 2400|>, 
>    False -> <|False -> 13180, True -> 2946|>|>

```
GroupBy[data, {Mod[#, 5] == 0&, Mod[#, 6] == 0&, Mod[#, 7] == 0&}, Map[Total, #, {-2}] &]
```

> <|True -> <|True -> <|False -> 1770, True -> 630|>,
>      False -> <|False -> 4150, True -> 455|>|>,
>      False -> <|True -> <|False -> 2778, True -> 168|>,
>      False -> <|False -> 11591, True -> 1589|>|>|>

```
GroupBy[data, {Mod[#, 5] == 0&, Mod[#, 6] == 0&, Mod[#, 7] == 0&}, Map[Max, #, {-2}] &]
```

> <|True -> <|True -> <|False -> 990, True -> 630|>, 
>      False -> <|False -> 965, True -> 385|>|>,
>    False -> <|True -> <|False -> 822, True -> 168|>, 
>      False -> <|False -> 989, True -> 826|>|>|>

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `red` form to effectively nest the `GroupBy` , and then finally a `red` application at the last level.

```
data = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1]; RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 50]];
GroupBy[data, Mod[#, 5] == 0 &,
  GroupBy[#, Mod[#, 6] == 0 &, Total] &]
```